# Get user's input and run command line

Tags: vbscript

When I paste a username in a box, the script will open command line and run a command to get user's information.

```
strInput = InputBox("prompt")
Dim oShell
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
oShell.Run "cmd net1 user &InputBox /domain" 
Set oShell = Nothing
```

I have tried the above, but it doesn't seem to work.  Please help me out.

Comment: How exacatly does it not work?

Comment: The cmd was still open, but no output was shown

Comment: I don't have a windows maschine here but shouldn't &InputBox be &strInput?

Comment: Possibly missing the `/c` switch for **cmd**: `"cmd /c net1 user &InputBox /domain"` But still, doubtful about passing the strInput to the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use /K switch, which tells CMD to execute the command listed. In addition, you need to pull the strInput variable out of the quotes:

```
strInput = InputBox("prompt")
Dim oShell
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
oShell.Run "cmd /K net1 user " & strInput & " /domain" 
Set oShell = Nothing
```